# How to place a comma after a percent symbol?

Tags: symbols

I would like to add a comma after a percent symbol in a LaTeX document. But if I do this I end up with space after a comma i.e "`140\% ,` " if I leave comma too close it does not show when I compile the report. Any idea how to fix this issue please?

Comment: `\%,` should do

Comment: Thanks very much. That worked.

Comment: B.t.w., typographically, there should be a `\,` between the number and \%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very basic thing about TeX is that `%` is a special character that introduces *comments*: everything on a line from `%` to the end is ignored.

Exception: `\%` ignores nothing and prints the percentage symbol.

> The increase in productivity has been 40%, so we’re happy.

would be input as

```
The increase in productivity has been 40\%, so we're happy.
```